# Definite Integral of a sinusoid, with absolute value?

Tags: definite-integrals, absolute-value

Using the Laplace Transform, I was able to calculate the value of
$$\int_0^\infty \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)dx$$
to be
$$\int_0^\infty \sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$
However, I can't seem to find the value of this closely related integral:
$$\int_0^\infty \bigg|\sin\bigg(\frac{1}{x^2}\bigg)\bigg|dx$$
The only thing that I thought to do was to change it into an infinite sum, but I have no idea how to evaluate integrals of this function over finite intervals.

Is there a closed form? If not, can it be expressed in terms of any other widely-used functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another method for those kind of integral is to compute the Fourier series coefficients of $|\sin(x)|$ to obtain

$$|\sin(x)| = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\cos(2 n x)-1)\frac{1}{1-4n^2}$$
Then
$$2\int_0^\infty |\sin(1/y^2)| dy = \int_0^\infty |\sin(x)| x^{-3/2}dx$$
$$ = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-4n^2}\int_0^\infty (\cos(2 n x)-1) x^{-3/2}dx$$
$$ = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-4n^2}n^{-1/2} \int_0^\infty (\cos(2 x)-1) x^{-3/2}dx$$
Where $\int_0^\infty (\cos(2 x)-1) x^{-3/2}dx$ can be expressed in term of $\Gamma(-1/2)$

So now the question reduces to evaluating the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^{-1/2}}{1-4n^2}$$

Comment: :-/ And I doubt that series has a closed form.